# How do I determine the values of $k$ for which $3x^2 + kx+12 = 0$ has no real solutions, $1$ real solution, and $2$ real solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I know that a point has to be $(0,12)$ just because of the $C$ term always being the y-intercept.

Please just tell me how to approach the problem/give tips, so that you are not doing my homework for me.

Comment: **Hint:** What if you use the [*Quadratic Formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Derivation_of_the_formula), solve for the two roots and then analyze the results?

Comment: Oh, I understand now.  So I just set the discriminant equal to zero, and then from that point I can say greater or less than that would have 2 or no real solutions.  Thanks.

Comment: Well technically you set $$\triangle = 0$$  $$\triangle> 0$$  $$\triangle < 0$$ and solve each of them for $k$. But be careful, when you set it $\triangle> 0$ you will get $2$ different intervals for example.

Comment: Okay, so then I think the answer would be $k > 12$ or $k < -12$ for 2 real solutions,  $k = 12$ is 1 solution, and $-12<k<12$ is no real solutions.

Comment: @GarrettSmith Yeah that's right!

Comment: Check the discriminant. Analyze the solution behavior for when the discriminant is 0, less than 0, or more than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: $\triangle = b^2 - 4ac = k^2 - 4(3)(12) = k^2 -144$. If $\triangle = 0$, it has $1$ real solution, $ < 0$ it has no real solution, and $ > 0$ it has $2$ real solutions.

Answer (score 1):

By the distributive property the equation is equivalently:

$$0=3\left(x^2+\frac{k}{3}x\right)+12$$

Subtracting $12$ from both sides of the equation.

$$-12=3\left(x^2+\frac{k}{3}x\right)$$

Dividing by $3$ on both sides of the equation.

$$-4=x^2+\frac{k}{3}x$$

Using the fact that $\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)^2=x^2+2\left(x\right)\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)+\frac{y^2}{4}$:

$$-4=\left(x+\frac{k}{6}\right)^2-\frac{k^2}{36}$$

$$\frac{k^2}{36}-4=\left(x+\frac{k}{6}\right)^2$$

Note now that if $u^2=c$ then $c=0$ gives one solution $0$, $c>0$ gives $2$ solutions $\pm \sqrt{c}$, and $c<0$ gives no real solutions.

With a little more thinking we can see that If we want $1$ real root we need:

$$\frac{k^2}{36}-4=0$$

If we want $2$ real solutions we need:

$$\frac{k^2}{36}-4>0$$

And finally no real solutions:

$$\frac{k^2}{36}-4<0$$